# schedule automatic uploading to sharepoint intranet site

Tags: sharepoint-server, file-upload, intranet

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions as to how to schedule automatic file uploads from a file on my desktop to my sharepoint intranet site. Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell! PowerShell can certainly be used to [upload files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237294/upload-file-to-sharepoint-document-library-using-powershell). And, you can just use [windows task scheduler](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx) to have it run on a schedule.

Comment: but how can i use it with ftp? because im pretty sure sharepoint sites dont have ftp built in

Comment: FTP? Did I miss something? The link I provided has a powershell script that uploads a doc, no ftp required.

Comment: i apologize i didn't realize that was an external hyperlink. do i just put that script in a batch file and run it?